# Setting Cell Value Based On Date Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, comparison

When the macro is run on any given date, it should check the current date and compare it to the different quarters in the year, and then change the value of certain cells based on what quarter we're in.

This is what I have so far that I'm trying to append to the end of our current macro:

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mgr, rsk As Range
    Dim d, Q1B, Q1E, Q2B, Q2E, Q3B, Q3E, Q4B, Q4E As Date

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mutual")
    Set mgr = ws.Range("B37")
    Set rsk = ws.Range("F37")

    d = Date
    Q1B = DateValue("01/01/2015")
    Q1E = DateValue("03/31/2015")
    Q2B = DateValue("04/01/2015")
    Q2E = DateValue("06/30/2015")
    Q3B = DateValue("07/01/2015")
    Q3E = DateValue("09/30/2015")
    Q4B = DateValue("10/01/2015")
    Q4E = DateValue("12/31/2015")

    If d <= Q1E Then
        mgr.Value = "Works 1"
        rsk.Value = "Works 2"
    End If


End Sub
```

Am I on the right path? I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write this, but this is my first time writing my own VBA code.

Comment: Just a heads-up: only `Q4E` is declares as `Date` in your code, all the other variables on that row are  `Variant`. VBA doesn't support declaration like that.

Comment: So I'd have to declare them all as Dates? Or would using Set in front of each statement work the same?

Comment: Yes, you would have to declare them all as date, but you can still do it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a macro try this formula instead

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2)=1,"Q"&INT((MONTH(A2)/3.25)+1)&" - "&YEAR(A2),"")
```

where A2 is your cell containing a date

Comment: Is that able to change the cell value per quarter? The reason I'm using a macro is because the cell value will change every quarter.My example only has one quarter filled out, but it will write different values for each quarter for the two cells.

Comment: I don't think I understand your comment. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, on each quarter I want the cell to display something different. From my understanding, the IF formula in the cell will put either a true or false statement once it completes its comparison. That will only give me two things to display instead of four for each quarter.

Comment: the formula I have will return the quarter and year based on the value in `A2`, so for instance if `A2 = 12/12/2014`, the formula will return `Q4 - 2014`